# Get X,Y position of element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to find X,Y position of mouse click relative to SVG element. The SVG element will be embedded in HTML.

```js
var svg = document.getElementById("svg1");
svg.addEventListener('click', event => {
  let x = event.clientX;
  let y = event.clientY;
  console.log(x, y);
});
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #fff;
}

svg {
  height: 100%;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="#52c927" />
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="25"   fill="white" />
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="15"  fill="red" />
</svg>
```

Want to subract offsetLeft and offsetTop of SVG  before printing X and Y in console. But not able to get those value

Comment: What browser are you using? "clientWidth" and "clientHeight" didn't work on SVG elements in Firefox up to version 52 (I think).

Comment: I'm using chrome `Version 83.0.4103.97 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get an element coordinates or size use [Element.getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

`event.target.getBoundingClientRect()` or `event.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect()` (for the element bound to the listener, rather than the one who propagated the event). Or directly with your cached Element reference constant `svg.getBoundingClientRect()`

```
const bcr = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
console.log(bcr.left, bcr.top)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

In your specific case, to get the **relative** mouse coordinates:

```
var svg = document.getElementById("svg1");
svg.addEventListener('click', event => {
  const bcr = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  const relative_x = event.clientX - bcr.left;
  const relative_y = event.clientY - bcr.top;
  console.log(relative_x, relative_y);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the coordinates relative to the element like this:

```js
var svg = document.getElementById("svg1");

svg.addEventListener('click', event => {
  const rect = svg.getBoundingClientRect();

  let x = event.clientX - rect.left;
  let y = event.clientY - rect.top;

  console.log(x, y);
});
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #fff;
}

svg {
  height: 100%;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="#52c927" />
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="25"   fill="white" />
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="15"  fill="red" />
</svg>
```